# R- Language - Is there a way to call a variable inside data frame in cases wherein it has same syntax with a built-in function?

Tags: r

For example,

1. I have a variable (column name) = "mode" in a sample data frame.

[image]

2. And there is a built-in function with R with its name "mode"

[image]

How do I tell my script to get values from the first one (1) and not on second one (2)?

My sample code:

```
mpg %>% 
 select("manufacturer", "model", "cty", "hwy") %>% 
 filter(manufacturer == "volkswagen") %>% 
 filter(mpg$class == "compact")
```

Comment: try `your_data_frame$mode` to get the column `mode` in your sample data frame (`your_data_frame` is the name of your sample data frame)

Comment: Hi @shafee, I got an error saying

Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = mpg$class == "compact"`.
✖ Input `..1` must be of size 27 or 1, not size 234.
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% filter(mpg$class == "compact")
 3. dplyr:::filter.data.frame(., mpg$class == "compact")
Execution halted

Comment: The comment doesn’t relate to the question body. Please add sufficient detail to the question itself with [edit] facilities.

Comment: DO NOT USE COMMENTS TO CLARIFY. Read the link material and also [MCVE].

Comment: Done. sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: This should not be an issue. R usually is able to infer if you are referring to a data object or a function. Your example code doesn't contain any reference to `mode`. What is the concrete issue you are facing?

Comment: You may want to read the [section](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#data--and-env-variables)  about the `.data` pronoun used in `dplyr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple way to do this in R. Where the name of your data frame is, "df":

```
df$mode

df[,"mode"]

df[,2]
```

These will all return values from the column and not from the built-in function.